# Woocommerce Discount only first of product type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to make a discount only happen for the first product with the attribute gallon in Woocommerce. So for example I add a paint product with the attribute gallon, that first product will be 10% off with coupon code test123. But if someone adds another paint with the attribute gallon, it should still only affect the first gallon added with a 10% off discount. Any other gallons of paint shouldn't receive the 10% off discount. Only the first one added.

Here is my code so far but I can't figure out how to get only one of the products with the attribute gallon with the discount.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'coupon_gallon', 99, 3 );
 
function coupon_gallon( $subtotal, $cart_item ){
global $woocommerce;
global $product;


$coupon_code = 'test123'; 
$item_data = $cart_item['data'];
$gallon = $item_data->get_attribute('pa_size');

 
if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code )) {
    
        if( $gallon == "Gallon") {

            //testing if triggered 
            echo '<div class="">YES!</div>';

            $newsubtotal = wc_price( $cart_item['data']->get_price() * 0.90 * 1 ); 
            $subtotal = sprintf( '<s>%s</s> %s', $subtotal, $newsubtotal ); 
            
            
        } else {
            echo '<div class="">NO!</div>';
        }
}
return $subtotal;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that using this hook may display the cart item subtotal differently, but that it will not affect the cart subtotal and the cart total?

Comment: Which hook do you suggest? @7uc1f3r

Comment: It depends on what your specific wish is. If you want to apply the new price automatically without coupon you can use the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook. If you want to show the old price next to the new price you can use your current hook. However, if you do want to use a coupon, you should keep in mind that the discount is displayed globally by default and not specifically per line item. 
In short, a combination of hooks is more likely the way to go, depending on your needs.